# What's this gesture called? Does it have a name?

Tags: anime

[image]

What's the meaning and what's this gesture called?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! could you provide more context? I mean Satoshi has got a present from her?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55371/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Wow, what looks like exactly the same image and everything. Exact dupe.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no single Japanese word for the gesture (I'm a native Japanese speaker).

If I talk about the gesture, I would use several words to describe it, such as 「鼻{はな}の下{した}を指{ゆび}でこする仕草{しぐさ}」 or more simply 「鼻をこする仕草」.

I have seen it on anime or manga, but have never seen anyone do it in real life. So it's a very アニメっぽい/マンガっぽい(anime-like/manga-like) gesture, I think. When a character makes the gesture, he/she often say 「ヘヘッ」 in Japanese.

Comment: Good information, but you didn't say what the gesture means.

Comment: You are right. The meaning of the gesture is a little hard to explain...

Typically, a character makes the gesture when he is trying to hide his feelings. Maybe he is happy and satisfied, and also he is trying to hide how happy he is because it is a little embarrassing for him to show his happy feelings to others. Or, maybe he is trying to talk about something secret but still hesitating.  In any case, he is probably a little embarrassed.

Comment: @MasaY great information! You should probably add that to answer, too